# does php's date_default_timezone_set adjust to daylight saving?

Tags: php, date, timezone, dst

Does php's date_default_timezone_set adjust to daylight saving?

I have this code, and wonder if it will always result in the correct Stockholm time?

```
  date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Stockholm');
  $timestamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Comment: In a word: it should, but it does not. In a timezone department PHP sucks big time. It always have had.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Yes this should always result in the right time.

Comment: And if your timezonedb is actual.

Comment: No, it doesn't! See also Jeffz's comment above.

Comment: No, it doesn't! You must check your thoughts with actual code before replying!

Answer (score 3):

PHP doesn't handle DST automatically. You have to check

```
if (date('I', time()) == 1) ... the time is in DST mode ("0" = not)
```

Then you should adust time accordingly.
(Note: 'I' in capital. I have just checked it and it works.)

Comment: How can you adjust the DST mode?

Answer (score -3):

As long as your timezone is listed in the following link, timestamp should be relative to the correct timezone.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: Correct time zone doesn't handle DST time automatically!

Comment: Again, no, no and no!  You guys should check your "solutions" with code before publishing them!